# merge multiple one-hot columns into a discrete column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Jones", "Jennifer", "Jack", "Sara", "Mick"],
    "age": [44, 22, 33, 44, 55],
    "weight": [44, 55, 66, 77, 99],
    "male": [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    "female": [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    "prefer_not_to_respond": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    "height": [175, 173, 160, 178, 190], 
    "is_smoking": [True, False, False, True, False]})
```

How can I select the "male", "female" and "prefer_not_to_respond" columns and merge them into one column called "gender" that will hold the value of the gender in every row (and delete the "male", "female" and "prefer_not_to_respond" columns)?
Would love a solution without using split method
Thank

Comment: Kindly post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Let us check `dot`

```
s = df[['male','female','prefer_not_to_respond']]
df['new'] = s.dot(s.columns)
df
Out[376]: 
       name  age  weight  ...  height  is_smoking                    new
0     Jones   44      44  ...     175        True                   male
1  Jennifer   22      55  ...     173       False  prefer_not_to_respond
2      Jack   33      66  ...     160       False                   male
3      Sara   44      77  ...     178        True                 female
4      Mick   55      99  ...     190       False                   male
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `idxmax`:

```
cols = ['male', 'female', 'prefer_not_to_respond']
df = df.assign(gender=df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)).drop(columns=cols)
print(df)

# Output
       name  age  weight  height  is_smoking                 gender
0     Jones   44      44     175        True                   male
1  Jennifer   22      55     173       False  prefer_not_to_respond
2      Jack   33      66     160       False                   male
3      Sara   44      77     178        True                 female
4      Mick   55      99     190       False                   male
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def f(x):
    if x['male'] == 1:
        return 'male'
    elif x['female'] == 1:
        return 'female'
    elif x['prefer_not_to_respond'] == 1:
        return 'prefer_not_to_respond'
df['gender'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
df = df.drop(['male', 'female', 'prefer_not_to_respond'], axis=1)
```

Comment: My mistake, I initially defined it as binary, but I mean there can be a lot of "gender" columns
I corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

```py
genders = ["male", "female", "prefer_not_to_respond"]
df = df.assign(gender=np.select(df[genders].eq(1).to_numpy().T, genders)).drop(columns=genders)
```

Comment: My mistake, I initially defined it as binary, but I mean there can be a lot of "gender" columns I corrected the question